# Get a String[][] array from a JSON response

Tags: java, json, string

I get the following JSON response from a server...

```
[["1","1"],["2","1"],["3","1"],["4","1"],["5","1"],["6","1"],["7","1"],["8","1"],["9","2"],["10","3"],["11","3"],["12","3"],["13","3"],["14","3"],["15","3"],["16","3"],["17","3"],["18","3"],["19","3"]]
```

It is in JSON format and i get it as a `String[]`, something like this...

```
String response = Response.getValue();
System.out.println(response) = [["1","1"],["2","1"],["3","1"],["4","1"],["5","1"],["6","1"],["7","1"],["8","1"],["9","2"],["10","3"],["11","3"],["12","3"],["13","3"],["14","3"],["15","3"],["16","3"],["17","3"],["18","3"],["19","3"]]
```

However, the response is a matrix of 2 values `[USU_ID, DEPARTMENT]` and i need to use it in a `String[][]`. How can I do this? I tried to use `StringTokenizer` but it doesn't work very well.

This is the code I have written...

```
public static String[][] Json2Matrix(String jsonStringArray) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        String[][] mstrJsonString = null;
        StringTokenizer tokElementos, tokSubelementos, tokTemp;
        //jsonArray = "[["a","b"],["c","d"],["e","f"]]";
        //jsonStringArray = jsonStringArray.replace("\"", "");
        //jsonArray = "[[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]]";
        jsonStringArray = jsonStringArray.substring(1, jsonStringArray.length() - 2);
        //jsonArray = "[a,b],[c,d],[e,f]";/

        //System.out.println(jsonStringArray);

        //JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonStringArray);

        //System.out.println(jsonArray.toString());

        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Prueba">
        tokElementos = new StringTokenizer(jsonStringArray, "[]");

        tokTemp = tokElementos;
        tokSubelementos = new StringTokenizer(tokTemp.nextToken(), ",");

        //System.out.println(tokElementos.countTokens());

        //System.out.println(tokElementos.nextToken());

        //System.out.println(tokSubelementos.countTokens()/2);

        mstrJsonString = new String[tokElementos.countTokens()][tokSubelementos.countTokens()];

        while (tokElementos.hasMoreTokens()) {
            tokSubelementos = new StringTokenizer(tokElementos.nextToken(), ",");
            j = 0;
            while (tokSubelementos.hasMoreTokens()) {

                mstrJsonString[i][j] = tokSubelementos.nextToken();
                System.out.println(i + "," + j + " " + mstrJsonString[i][j]);
                j++;
            }
            i++;

        }
        //</editor-fold>
        return mstrJsonString;
    }
```

and i get this as the output...

```
run:
1,0 "2"
1,1 "1"
3,0 "3"
3,1 "1"
5,0 "4"
5,1 "1"
7,0 "5"
7,1 "1"
9,0 "6"
9,1 "1"
11,0 "7"
11,1 "1"
13,0 "8"
13,1 "1"
15,0 "9"
15,1 "2"
17,0 "10"
17,1 "3"
19,0 "11"
19,1 "3"
21,0 "12"
21,1 "3"
23,0 "13"
23,1 "3"
25,0 "14"
25,1 "3"
27,0 "15"
27,1 "3"
29,0 "16"
29,1 "3"
31,0 "17"
31,1 "3"
33,0 "18"
33,1 "3"
35,0 "19"
35,1 "3"
```

It gets the correct values, but the incorrect Indexes. Could someone please help me correct this.

Comment: I'm sorry, do you want to write your own json parser? Why not use http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: String[][] nuevo = JsonParser.fromJson(jsonStringArray, String[][].class); that was my solution.... oh god, sry for my stupid question... im very junior in this. Thanks lukas :)

Comment: in C# I would say that you're deserializing a List<List<string>> if that helps at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a JSON parsers saves you a lot of effort than writing a primitive one yourself.

I have used these Java based JSON parsers:

1. Jackson [http://jackson.codehaus.org/]
2. Google's GSON [http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/]

I recommend Google's GSON as :

1. You can serialize/deserialize json strings into Java Objects [POJOs], without annotations [uses variable names].
2. Can easily serialize/deserialize deep object hierarchies.
3. It has decent support for Java Generics

Answer (score 0):

http://json.org/java/

Hope this helps, I was using this a few months ago for using JSON with java and it worked really well(*also was using netbeans)